# Clicking on taskbar icon now switches windows instead of displaying all of them. How can I revert?

Tags: kde, plasma5

I notices since about a week ago that when I would click on an icon from the taskbar (eg. firefox), when multiple instance of that program are opened (ie. many firefox windows are opened), it would displaying all opened instances of that program and allow me to click on the instance I wanted. Now it simply cycles though all instances.

I can somewhat recreate the previous behavior. I set (system settings -> workspace -> workspace behavior -> screen edge) it so that when I move my cursor to the top right the option "Present Windows" happens. I have a screenshot of that effect.

[image: example]

Previously, when I would click on an icon in the taskbar it would present all of that icon's opened windows similar to the screenshot. Now every click cycles through to a new opened instance. How can I revert to the previous settings?

I am running on arch linux version 5.9.1-arch1-1, and kde plasma 5.20.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To revert to the previous settings, right-click on the taskbar and choose "Configure taskbar with symbols". Then, go to the tab "Behavior" on the left and choose "Show 'Present Windows' effect" in the "Clicking grouped task" combobox. Make sure to apply your changes.

Note: The exact wording of these options might differ slightly.